# Creating an expanding image on click with setInterval & clearInterval?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a thumbnail image which animates into a larger version and stays as that version for 5 seconds before returning to its original size when the 'View' button is clicked. I'm absolutely required to use the window.setInterval and window.clearInterval methods.

Here is my attempt so far: https://jsfiddle.net/Lm1y51pb/1/

```
var myVar = setInterval(function(){ enlargeImg() }, 5000); // expand for 5 seconds

    function enlargeImg() {
      var img = document.getElementById("myImg"); 
      var width = 0;
      var height = 0;
      // how do I expand the image with this so far?
    }

    function myStopFunction() {

        if(5000 secs have passed)
        clearInterval(myVar);
    }
```

I'm having problems in enlarging the image and mainly in the myStopFunction() where if 5 seconds have passed, stop the above function.

The max width and height is 500px.

Comment: `img.style.width = 'auto';` and `img.style.height = 'auto';`

Comment: 'larger version' means? What is max width/height?

Comment: @haim770 awesome, how do you think I can assign `img.style.width = 'auto';` to a javascript variable?

Comment: @nevermind max width/height is 500px

Comment: @SterlingKing, do you want this functionality> https://jsfiddle.net/Lz6qnjLp/ (code is terrible, it should/could be much better, so i will not post it as an answer:))

Comment: @nevermind yes! Shame you didn't post as answer, thank you :)!

Comment: @SterlingKing, np, if i make it better, maybe... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```js
var myVar = setInterval(function(){ enlargeImg() }, 5000);

function enlargeImg() {
  var img = document.getElementById("myImg"); 
  var width = 0;
  var height = 0;
  img.style.width = 'auto';
  img.style.height = 'auto';
}
```

```html
<img id="myImg" src="http://i.imgur.com/XCCso5f.jpg" alt="" width="250" height="250" /> 
<button onclick="enlargeImg()">View</button>
```

Comment: Interesting but the code doesn't run @slonski do you mind using JSFiddle or something else?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, fixed

Comment: One more thing, I've tried implementing setInterval and clearInterval in the code but it doesn't work, any suggestions? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oYPgxO

Comment: I added it back. You don't need to clear interval in this case

Comment: In your codepen you forgot () after enlargeImg within interval function, here's correct version: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RoYNGw

Comment: Oh ok thanks, maybe it's my javascript but when I click 'view' and wait 5 seconds the image remains expanded. Maybe I need to put some sort of if...else condition.

Comment: Thank you! @Slonski